# lldb swift not printing debug variables

Tags: xcode, swift, debugging, lldb

Swift LLDB in Xcode 6.4 is not printing values of any local variables inside my framework.
Here's what I have discovered so far.

```
(lldb) frame variable --no-args
cell = <Unable to determine byte size.>

(lldb) register read pc // get the current program counter value
  rip = 0x00000001072177cf  

(lldb) image lookup -va  0x00000001072177cf
Variable: id = {0x000a93a7}, name = "cell", type= "<NULL>", location = DW_OP_fbreg(-64), decl = CustomCollectionViewCell.swift:321
```

It seems like it's not able to find the type.

```
(lldb) image lookup -t CustomCollectionViewCell
(lldb)
```

I can see the image containing the type is loaded.

```
(lldb) image list
...
/path/to/CustomFramework
```

Moreover this file also contains the symbol.

```
$strings /path/to/CustomFramework | grep CustomCollectionViewCell
_TtC17CustomFramework24CustomCollectionViewCell
```

I do seem to have debug symbols since:

```
(lldb) script lldb.target.module['/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/23A3AF01-4F87-439F-B2F7-36E7BD09390B/MyApp.app/Frameworks/CustomFramework.framework/CustomFramework'].GetNumCompileUnits()
74
```

In addition the object file of the compiled swift file has the variable and type.

```
$ dwarfdump /path/to/FileUsingCell.o
0x00003140:                                 TAG_variable [44]
                                             AT_location( fbreg -8 )
                                             AT_name( "cell" )
                                             AT_decl_file( "CustomCollectionViewCell.swift" )
                                             AT_decl_line( 324 )
                                             AT_type( {0x0000133d} ( CustomCollectionViewCell ) )
```

Still I am not able to lookup the type.

I have checked that no striping is happening in the copy phase, and the release is debug.

Any ideas? I'd appreciate any help.